# scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a, b;
    char c1, c2;
    printf("Enter something: ");
    scanf("%d", &a); // line 1
    printf("Enter other something: ");
    scanf("%d", &b); // line 2

    printf("Enter a char: ");
    scanf("%c", &c1); // line 3
    printf("Enter another char: ");
    scanf("%c", &c2); // line 4

    printf("Done"); // line 5

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

As I read in the C book, the author says that `scanf()` left a newline character in the buffer, therefore, the program does not stop at line 4 for user to enter the data, rather it stores the new line character in `c2` and moves to line 5.

Is that right?

However, does this only happen with `char` data types? Because I did not see this problem with `int` data types as in line 1, 2, 3. Is it right?

Comment: It is sometimes suggested that `fflush(stdin)` can be used before the call to `scanf()` for a single character.  Please read [Using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/) for a discussion of the pros and cons and alternatives to that method (which works, more or less, on Windows, and does not work most other places).

Comment: Could you please let us know which book you are referring to .?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Using `fflush(stdin)` is plain **undefined behaviour.**

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) function skips leading whitespace automatically before trying to parse conversions other than characters.  The character formats (primarily `%c`; also scan sets `%[…]` — and `%n`) are the exception; they don't skip whitespace.

Use `" %c"` with a leading blank to skip optional white space.  Do not use a trailing blank in a `scanf()` format string.

Note that this still doesn't consume any trailing whitespace left in the input stream, not even to the end of a line, so beware of that if also using [`getchar()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) or [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) on the same input stream.  We're just getting scanf to skip over whitespace *before* conversions, like it does for `%d` and other non-character conversions.

---

Note that non-whitespace "directives" (to use [POSIX scanf terminology](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)) other than conversions, like the literal text in `scanf("order = %d", &order);` doesn't skip whitespace either.  The literal `order` has to match the next character to be read.

So you probably want `" order = %d"` there if you want to skip a newline from the previous line but still require a literal match on a fixed string, [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923312/scanf-run-twice-instead-of-one-time-at-assembly-x86-64).

Comment: `%c`, `%n`, `%[]` are the 3 specified expectations that do not consume leading whitespace.

Comment: @chux So Does in Other Cases, The scanf clears all the whitespaces before in the buffer or ignores them for they input but they are still there?

Comment: @SurajJain Yes,

Comment: See [Trailing blank in `scanf()` format string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-difference-between-scanfd-and-scanfd) and [`scanf()` asking twice for input while I expect it to ask only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740024/scanf-asking-twice-for-input-while-i-expect-it-to-ask-only-one/15740124#15740124) for a discussion of trailing blanks in format strings.  They're a bad idea — astoundingly bad if you expect human interaction and bad for program interaction.

Comment: This answer does a very good job of explaining that `scanf()` reads and then formats, and not just read according to the format.

Answer (score 42):

Use `scanf(" %c", &c2);`. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 14):

Another option (that I got from [here](https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1352443831&id=1043284392)) is to read and discard the newline by using the *assignment-supression option*. To do that, we just put a format to read a character with an asterisk between `%` and `c`:

```
scanf("%d%*c",&a); // line 1
scanf("%c%*c",&c1); // line 3
```

`scanf` will then read the next char (that is, the newline) but not assign it to any pointer.

In the end, however, I would second [the FAQ's last option](https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1352443831&id=1043284392):

> Or, depending on your requirements, you could also forget about scanf()/getchar(), use fgets() to get a line of text from the user and parse it yourself.

Comment: The trouble with this technique is that if the user types `a` then space then newline, the suppressed character conversion reads the space and still leaves the newline.  If the user types `supercalifragilisticexpialidocious` when you expect `a`, you've got a lot of extra characters to deal with.  You can never tell whether a trailing suppressed conversion succeeds, either — they're not counted in the return from `scanf()`.

Comment: This only discards *one* character. Placing a space before `%` will discard *any amount* of leading whitespace (including none).

Comment: @WeatherVane: For a line like `123\n`, `"%d %*c"` will have the space in the format string consume whitespace and then `%*c` consume *the first non-whitespace byte of the next line*.  (Just trailing whitespace in the format string will wait until there's a non-whitespace character, which might be ok if reading from a file, but not for interactive input.  Trailing `" %*c"` does that and then discards the first non-whitespace character, so if waiting for the next line now is acceptable at all, just use trailing whitespace.)

Answer (score 12):

To echo what I have posted in [another answer about C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52720064/6372809): I suggest to toss `scanf()` away, to never use it, and to instead use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.

The reason for this is, that at least in Unix-like systems by default, the terminal your CLI program runs on does some processing of the user input before your program sees it. It buffers input until a newline is entered, and allows for some rudimentary line editing, like making backspace work.

So, you can never get a single character at a time, or a few single characters, just a full line. But that's not what e.g. `scanf("%d")` processes, instead it processes just the digits, *and stops there*, leaving the rest buffered in the C library, for a future `stdio` function to use. If your program has e.g.

```
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &a);

printf("Enter a word: ");
scanf("%s", word);
```

and you enter the line `123 abcd`, it completes *both* `scanf()`s at once, but only after a newline is given. The first `scanf()` doesn't return when a user has hit space, even though that's where the number ends (because at that point the line is still in the terminal's line buffer); and the second `scanf()` doesn't wait for you to enter another line (because the input buffer already contains enough to fill the `%s` conversion).

This isn't what users usually expect!

Instead, they expect that hitting enter completes the input, and if you hit enter, you either get a default value, or an error, with possibly a suggestion to please really just give the answer.

You can't really do that with `scanf("%d")`. If the user just hits enter, nothing happens. Because `scanf()` is still waiting for the number. The terminal sends the line onward, but your program doesn't see it, because `scanf()` eats it. You don't get a chance to react to the user's mistake.

That's also not very useful.

Hence, I suggest using `fgets()` or `getline()` to read a full line of input at a time. This exactly matches what the terminal gives, and always gives your program control after the user has entered a line. What you do with the input line is up to you, if you want a number, you can use `atoi()`, `strtol()`, or even `sscanf(buf, "%d", &a)` to parse the number. `sscanf()` doesn't have the same mismatch as `scanf()`, because the buffer it reads from is limited in size, and when it ends, it ends -- the function can't wait for more.

<sup>(`fscanf()` on a regular file can also be fine if the file format is one that supports how it skims over newlines like any whitespace. For line-oriented data, I'd still use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.)</sup>

---

So, instead of what I had above, use something like this:

```
printf("Enter a number: ");

fgets(buf, bufsize, stdin);
sscanf(buf, "%d", &a);
```

or, actually, check the return value of `sscanf()` too, so you can detect empty lines and otherwise invalid data:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const int bufsize = 100;
    char buf[bufsize];
    int a;
    int ret;
    char word[bufsize];

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    fgets(buf, bufsize, stdin);

    ret = sscanf(buf, "%d", &a);

    if (ret != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Ok, you don't have to.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter a word: ");
    fgets(buf, bufsize, stdin);

    ret = sscanf(buf, "%s", word);
    if (ret != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "You make me sad.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("You entered %d and %s\n", a, word);
}
```

Of course, if you want the program to insist, you can create a simple function to loop over the `fgets()` and `sscanf()` until the user deigns to do what they're told; or to just exit with an error immediately. Depends on what you think your program should do if the user doesn't want to play ball.

---

You could do something similar e.g. by looping over `getchar()` to read characters until a newline after `scanf("%d")` returned, thus clearing up any garbage left in the buffer, but that doesn't do anything about the case where the user just hits enter on an empty line. Anyway, `fgets()` would read until a newline, so you don't have to do it yourself.

Comment: `fgets()`/`getline()` and then `sscanf()` or `strtol()`, etc., also has another huge advantage over using `scanf()` directly.  ***When*** the program encounters unexpected input, the input stream isn't left in an unknown state where recovery without losing data can be impossible.

Comment: For further reading about alternatives to `scanf`: [What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58403537/12149471) Also, this guide may be helpful: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 8):

Use `getchar()` before calling second `scanf()`.

```
scanf("%c", &c1);
getchar();  // <== remove newline
scanf("%c", &c2);
```

Comment: This works provided that the user didn't type anything else — trailing blanks, for example.  But it isn't as good as a loop that scans to the next newline: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;` (written over three lines when not in a comment).  It is often sufficient; it is not foolproof (and you have to remember that fools are very clever about crashing things).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler
 do you mean written over two lines? ``int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;``

Comment: @john: It can be one, two, three lines or more — the compiler doesn't care.  Left to my own devices, it would be three lines: the declaration, the loop control and the loop body. 
 The semicolon denoting the empty loop body would be on a line on its own to emphasize that it is intentional (as recommended by K&R).

Answer (score 0):

Two workarounds. One is catch the extra whitespace trickly.

```c
getchar(); // (1) add `getchar()`
scanf("%c", &c1);

scanf(" %c", &c1); // (2) add whitespace before %c
```

The other is using `fgets()` to instead `scanf()`. Note: `gets()` is unsafe, see [why gets is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

By contrast, I would prefer to recommend the second way. Because it's more **readable** and **maintainable**. For example, in first way, you must think a while before adding/moving some `scanf()`.

Answer (score -5):

```
/*Take char input using scanf after int input using scanf just use fflush(stdin) function  after int input */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
  int x;
  char y;
  clrscr();
  printf(" enter an int ");
  scanf("%d",&x);
  fflush(stdin);
  printf("\n Now enter a char");
  scanf("%c",&y);
  printf("\n X=%d and Y=%c",x,y);
  getch();
}
```

Comment: Note the caveats about [Using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/15168).

Comment: `conio.h` is not part of ISO C, but is a [platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform)-specific header. The functions `clrscr` and `getch` are also platform-specific. Note that the question is not tagged with any particular platform, so that the question does not apply to any particular platform. Therefore, if you decide to provide a platform-specific answer, you should at least clearly mark it as such and specify to which platform your answer applies.